# How to customize the style of widgets in azure Databricks, like width of a dropdown?

Tags: azure, widget, databricks

How to control width of widgets in azure databricks notebooks for data analytics, customize the width of a drop down box.?

I tried to install python module ipywidgets but it is not working and i did't see any options for customizing the widgets.
https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/widgets.html

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include more informationen, what did not work, what you tried, ...

Comment: How to control width of widgets in azure databricks notebooks for data analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In azure databricks we can't able to customize the widget's size it's automatic but we can able sort the widgets using serial numbers. Maybe in future, it will added by the databricks community

[Azure databricks document](https://docs.databricks.com/)

```
dbutils.widgets.text("01.FirstName","") 
dbutils.widgets.text("02.LastName","") 
dbutils.widgets.text("03.Age","")
```

Answer (score 1):

The UI has changed since this answer was given. You can now edit the width of a widget using the databricks interface. Click the edit button at the top right of the widgets bar.

[image]

Then click and drag the widget to the desired width:

[image]

Comment: Though weirdly you need to have CAN_MANAGE permission on the notebook for this button to be accessible. Fine when it's in your personal workspace but not great when you're publishing these for other people to use.
https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/widgets.html#configure-widget-settings